# How to get/edit the script of the built-in "Character Controller" component?

Tags: unity, character-controller

I was using Unity's Character Controller component, but I found it very limited and wanted to tweak some things.

I thought about creating my own character controller from scratch, but it would be much easier if I could start with Unity's Character Controller script and just tweak what I need.

How can do that?

Comment: You could always open the source of the CharacterController or just extend the existing one.

Comment: How do I open the source?

Comment: For me it is in Rider double left shift and the name. https://forum.unity.com/threads/character-controller-source-code.532107/ there they claim it is just a wrapper for the PhysX Controller

Comment: @Zibelas I think this would be worth sharing as an answer.

Comment: Yes. If @Zibelas writes the answer I can mark as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shipped CharacterController is located in the `UnityEngine.PhysicsModule.dll`. Now depending on the IDE you are using, you could still take a look at the source. For Rider the shortcut to search for everywhere is double left shift. Entering CharacterController and opening the file is decompiling as good as it can for a readable format. That does not mean you can make changes to the file and expect it to work.

But after taking a look at the soure, you will notice that there is no actual logic in the Controller. A quick google brought this one up: [Source for CharacterController](https://forum.unity.com/threads/character-controller-source-code.532107/) where the post claims, that Unity is just using the PhysX from the physics engine and wrote a wrapper for it.

You could now write a wrapper for the wrapper and just cherry pick the functionality you want or go right away with your own CharacterController. If you want to take a look at the full source of it, it should be available here: [NVIDIAGameWorks PhysX](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/PhysX/blob/4050bbfdc2699dfab7edbf0393df8ff96bbe06c5/physx/source/physxcharacterkinematic/src/CctCharacterController.cpp)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to create special cases that would prevent the isGrounded bool to be true. I'll change my approach then.

Comment: The character controller offers a quick and easy way to test your game. It has a lot of drawbacks as well for that it doesn’t respond nor uses physics in any way. Depending on your game, you might be faster writing your own fully instead.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the help